# data displays erroneously after five minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC site that after ~5 minutes, alters how it displays string data on a partial.  The data should read:

*New Auto - up to 36 months*  and then the rate

... but after five minutes it just displays:

*up to 36 months*

I am unable to reproduce this issue in testing or local versions of the code.  If I upload the DLL, it reverts to the proper display, but only for about five minutes.

Any thoughts on what to overcome this issue would be most appreciated.

EDIT (added code)
The display part is a partial:

```
@model AFCUResponsive.RateViewer

      <div class="col">
        <h5>Featured Rates</h5>
        <form method="post" action="">
          <div class="tabber">
            <ul class="tabs list-unstyled">
              <li class="selected"><a href="#tab1">Loans</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tab2">Deposits</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Loans tab -->
            <div class="tab" id="tab1">
                @foreach (var item in Model.FeaturedRatesLoan())
                {
                    <div class="rate"> 
                        <span class="left">@item.LoanName <br /></span>
                        <span class="right"> As low as <span class="percent">@item.APR_WDD % APR*</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of rate -->
                }
            </div> 
            <!-- end of tab -->
            <!-- Deposits tab -->
           <div class="tab" id="tab2">
                @foreach (var item in Model.FeaturedRatesDeposit())
                {
                    <div class="rate"> 
                        <span class="left">@item.AccountName <br /></span>
                        <span class="right"><span class="percent">@item.APY.ToString("N2") % APY*</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- end of rate -->
                }
            </div>
            <!-- end of tab -->
            <div class="rate" style="margin:11px 0 0;">
                    <a class="btn" href="@Url.Content("~/Appleweb/Rates")" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'home page', 'CTA BTN ', 'see_all_rates'])">See All Rates</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end of tabber -->
        </form>
      </div>
```

Thanks @CodeCaster for the questions.  In order:

> How do you build the string "New Auto - up to 36 months"?

This string is a database pull.  It's all one field, so the fact that it's choosing to edit this is why I'm leaning towards the framework.

> How do you determine that it changes after 5 minutes? Do you refresh the page, or does it automagically remove the "New Auto -" part?

I've timed the page after upload of a new DLL and hit refresh until the text disappears which is ~ 5 minutes.

> Does it happen in all browsers, for all users, on all machines?

Yes, although we don't have Macs 'round here.  Just browserstack.

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML containing the rate, and any Javascript that references it?  This kind of seems like a front-end issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce. What is the _relevant_ part of the partial there? How do you build the string "New Auto - up to 36 months"? Where do you print it? How do you determine that it changes after 5 minutes? Do you refresh the page, or does it automagically remove the "New Auto -" part? Does it happen in all browsers, for all users, on all machines? You should first of all always suspect your own code, not the framework you use. Show your relevant code.

Comment: Still not enough info. MVC will never decide to randomly truncate strings, especially not from the beginning of the string. Is the entire string still present in the HTML? Is it in the model? Does it only happen for this particular string? How do you read from the database? Is the site visited through a (caching) proxy that may alter the HTML for whatever reason? Do you use any CSS or JS that could do this? What do you see if you "inspect element"? To emphasize: _you_ need to analyze this. There's nobody going to say _"Oh yeah you need to remove the `randomlyTrimStart` appsetting"_. :)

Comment: I understand that MVC isn't the one truncating the string, I don't believe I ever made such a statement.  Clearly the string is truncated by the server, since it's not repeatable on local or staging environments.  

I'm sure there is someone who has experienced this and can provide an answer as to what config or IIS setting might be causing such an issue.